# $p^2+a^2$ can be a squarefree number with all prime divisors less than $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

Let $p$ be a prime $\ge 31$.

Is there an integer $a < p$ such that $p^2 + a^2$ is a squarefree and all of its prime divisors are less than $p$?

For example, for $p=31$, $31^2+5^2 = 986 = 2 \times 17 \times 29$.

Any comments are welcome.

PS. I thank Robert Israel for checking upto $3 \times 10^{6}$.

I think it's hard to prove this problem. But, is it possible to prove if we omit the squarefree condition?

Comment: For any particular prime, this can be answered by a short computation.  What computations have you already done?

Comment: It's true for all primes from $31$ to $3 \times 10^6$.

Comment: Such a result, without the square-free condition, should be obtainable by combining the insights of this paper (https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/6023) and this paper by Fouvry and Iwaniec (http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa79/aa7935.pdf); see also this paper by Lam, Schindler, and myself for a newer perspective: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1112/jlms.12336